# Deserialize a tree having another tree as reference

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde

Suppose that I have a simple yaml file that I can deserialize into a tree of the following form:

```rust
enum TreeOne {
  End(EndTypeOne),
  Nesting(HashMap<String, TreeOne>)
}

struct EndTypeOne { 
  // ... 
}
```

Then I have another yaml file that should have the same structure, but its `EndType` could be anything: strings, numbers, or even continue as valid yaml and be parsed to a `serde_yaml::Value`.

```rust
enum TreeTwo {
  End(EndTypeTwo),
  Nesting(HashMap<String, TreeTwo>)
}

enum EndTypeTwo {
  String(String),
  U64(u64),
  Map(HashMap<String, String>),
  InnerYaml(serde_yaml::Value),
}
```

That I know of, there would be no way to distinguish between `TreeTwo::End(EndTypeTwo::Yaml(_))` and `TreeTwo::Nesting(HashMap<String, TreeTwo>)` if the input allows both.

Is there a way to successfully deserialize this new structure by being informed of what the shape should be by an existing `TreeOne` value? Or should I just deserialize it with the implementations that `#[derive(Deserialize)]` provide (or into a `Value` as an intermediate format) and then try to process it?

Comment: How would you do it? I mean, stop thinking how **serde** will do that, and think how **you** will do that. Suppose you're given the task of deserializing this file manually. How would you decide which variant to use?